# With GIT show commits older than a specific date with specific format

Tags: git, bash, date, git-commit

I need to print the latest 10 commits that are older than a specific date with specific format. I need to handle the date, obtained through the bash command:

```
 date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"
```

I tried some options, but so far nothing

```
e.g.: git log -5 --no-merges --format=format:%cd --after=201506301524
```

Comment: Is that not working because git doesn't like that date format (you are getting an error)? Is it not working because you aren't getting the commit you expect? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--until` instead of `--after` and furthermore, the correct date format, but you can use `date` to convert it:

```
git log --no-merges --format=format:%cd -10 --until "$(date -d "$(echo "201506301524" | sed 's/....$/ &/')")"
```

`$(echo "201506301524" | sed 's/....$/ &/')` converts
the date to `20150630 1524` which is a valid input format for date.

Answer (score 2):

You have to format the date, only numbers won't do. Use one of those:

```
--after=2015-06-30-15:24:00
--after=2015-06-30:16:24:00
--after="2015-06-30 16:24:00"
```

All of those formats were accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use the right date format (`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00"`):

```
git log --no-merges --format=format:%cd --after="2015-06-30 15:24:00"
```

Now, you can use `--reverse` to get oldest commits first:

```
git log --reverse --no-merges --format=format:%cd --after="2015-06-30 15:24:00"
```

Unfortunately, `git log --reverse -10` won't return what you want, as it'll grap the 10 latest commits, *then* reverse the list (which means you'll get the same list, whatever the specified date).

**An alternative is to use `head` on this result:**

```
git log --reverse --no-merges --format=format:%cd --after="2015-06-30 15:24:00" | head -10
```